# Google sheets current user

Tags: google-sheets

I was hoping you could help me,

I'm looking to display the current user of a google sheet in a cell to pull a vlookup off,

I have added a script to pull the logged in username into a script gallery but I am unable to dump the logger.log information into a google sheet

Any information would be great,

thank you
Nigel

Answer (score 17):

This works fine :) remember how to use getRange(row,column) as it will be your best friend now you are scripting..

```
function setActiveUser() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // GET EMAIL ADDRESS OF ACTIVE USER
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);

  //SET CELL A1 TO EMAIL ADDRESS OF ACTIVE USER
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(email);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an error `You do not have permission to call getActiveUser`. Do you have any idea why? I'm using google sheets for business and I'm not the sheet's owner but I have edit permission. Thanks!