# Google Sheets: highlight certain users' edits

Tags: google-sheets

I want to conditionally format a Google Sheet for specific users. Basically, Teacher#1's edits would appear yellow while Teacher#2's are green. Unfortunately the "conditional formatting" tool in Sheets doesn't have this option. Protecting certain cells doesn't work because of the regularity of changes in editors.. I simply want to see editors, not restrict them. Another suggestion should be to use the "Revision History" option.. but this doesn't seem practical for finding a certain editor's changes over several months using several sheets (that several editors have access to).

So the direction I was thinking of going was having a function with an OnEdit trigger that would grab the email (all users must login) and then highlight the last edit.

[Here is the URL for a public Google Sheet I duplicated](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FtMkSftE-_19LrJZPQCV-daQc9H2ra9HRXvy6xq68ZA/edit?usp=sharing). There, you'll see one of many Weeks sheets. Then there is a control panel with colors that would be associated with each user (teacher).

I copied some script from [another StackOverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334894/google-sheets-current-user) to get started.

```
function setActiveUser() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // GET EMAIL ADDRESS OF ACTIVE USER
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);

  //HIGHLIGHT LAST EDITED CELL BASED ON OF ACTIVE USER'S PREDETERMINED COLOR
  sheet.getRange(here is where I need to locate last edited cell).setBackgroundColor("here is where I need to color it based on the "Control Panel" sheet colors");
```

Hopefully someday Google will allow this kind of Conditional Formatting, but in the meantime it will help my school in Latin America a ton.

Thank you for considering!

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code should be:

```
function onEdit() {
```

And the last lines should be something like this: (edit)

```
  //HIGHLIGHT LAST EDITED CELL BASED ON OF ACTIVE USER'S PREDETERMINED COLOR
  var teacherName = ss.getRangeByName("TeacherName").getValues().map(function(array) { return array[0]; });
  var teacherColor = ss.getRangeByName("TeacherColor").getValues().map(function(array) { return array[0]; });
  var nameIdx = teacherName.indexOf(email);
  if(nameIdx > -1)
    sheet.getActiveCell().setBackground(teacherColor[nameIdx]);
```

To get it working, you should first run the code in the Script Editor and authorize it. And `TeacherName` and `TeacherColor` should be set to named ranges beforehand. Test sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sJuwQ-Wre_Np69rDeMmZWPYvJbmpZ5dwjbpkd79Eb6M/).

Comment: Sangbok, it's nice that the test sheet highlights after editing, but it looks like everyone's edits are in yellow. My hope was to have certain people's edits show up in certain colors. In the tab "Control Panel" you can see that I have a list of 6 teachers. Instead of "Teacher#1", I would have that teacher's email. What I would want is to look and see who is editing the sheet and do a vlookup-type script that would highlight any edit yellow if made by Teacher#2 (but again, the email address would have to be there, not "Teacher#2).   Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: @AaronSmith I modified the code. Try it via my test sheet. Hope you get the hang of it.